# Is System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient obsolete in 4.7?

Tags: c#, .net

Few days back I visited a [blog](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/MailKit-MimeKit-Official) that said `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` is obsolete and an open source library [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) and [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) is replacing it.

I can see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?view=netframework-4.7) for that but not finding the same in [reference code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs) and in library. Is it obsolete or not?

```
[System.Obsolete("SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead")]
public class SmtpClient : IDisposable
```

Comment: [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is marked as obsolete in docs, but not in the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/1876)

Comment: Seems likely (see previous comment) this is a documentation bug.

Comment: It is not "MSDN" doc, but the new Microsoft Docs. That's enough to tell if anything is obsolete in most cases, as documentation was separate from the source files, and can be updated more often to reflect latest changes. Microsoft plans to move documentation back to the source files, but the progress is not as fast as everyone wishes.

Comment: The docs are not all human generated.  Much of it is done through reflection of the final binaries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Liam pointed out, this is obsolete due to a bug in documentation.
[Is System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient obsolete in 4.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517434/is-system-net-mail-smtpclient-obsolete-in-4-7/51794440#51794440)

Comment: **All I can do using** `SmtpClient`, ***can I do it using MailKit - MimeKit?***

Comment: I can verify the official recommendation from their documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: Not obsolete: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/SmtpClient.cs

Comment: @kiquenet MailKit supports all functions and even much more.

Comment: Here's hoping mailkit and mimekit get into .net standard

Comment: **This is incorrect**, it was marked as obsolete because of the [bug in the documentation process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794440/542251). This should of been marked as obsolete in some frameworks, but **not .Net 4.7**. Full [GitHub issue information here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/1876)

Comment: This seems absurd.  Mailkit doesn't even provide any .config.  How can such a fundamental thing such as sending an email be so poorly supported in a framework as mature as .NET?

Comment: https://askyourquestions.info/2019/07/15/how-to-replace-update-code-for-system-net-mail-smtpclient-class-with-mailkit/ I converted my all old code to mailkit format you can do config like this.SmtpClient smtpClient2 = new SmtpClient();
                    smtpClient2.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"].ToString() != "")
                        smtpClient2.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"].ToString());

Comment: Documentation bug or not, SmtpClient is still marked as obsolete in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8 (April 2020)

Comment: Over a year later, it is still marked as obsolete, and I see no way to report this as a bug in their documentation.  They seem to only allow reporting bugs for a limited set in their docs.  Why wouldn't they recommend Microsoft Graph as a replacement anyway?

Comment: I was finally able to report this as an issue and they have finally fixed it.
I suggested recommending Microsoft Graph as a replacement, but they said it was not an adequate replacement since it can only connect to outlook.com and similar services.  They are still recommending the non-Microsoft MailKit library.

Answer (score 15):

It is **not** obsolete in .NET Framework 4.7.  It was inadvertently documented as such in the API Browser due to a [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/1876) in the automated documentation generator.  However, it *is* obsolete in Mono and Xamarin.

Comment: On the contrary, it's actually and functionally obsolete. Just because the attribute is missing doesn't mean that all of the problems suddenly disappeared, or that the class should be used

Answer (score 10):

> ... Microsoft has officially marked a .NET class as being replaced by an open source library.
> The documentation for `SmtpClient` now reads,
>
> > Obsolete("SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we
> > strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and
> > https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead")

> **The main problem with SmtpClient is that it has a confusing connection lifecycle.**
> Connecting to a SMTP server can be time-consuming, especially if authentication is enabled, so each `SmtpClient` object has an internal connection pool.
>
> This is a rather strange design. Consider for a moment a typical database connection. When you call Dispose on a `SqlClient`, the underlying connection is returned to the pool. When you create a new `SqlClient`, the pool is checked for an active connection with the same connection string.
>
> With `SmtpClient`, calling `Dispose` closes all of the connections and drains that object's connection pool. **This means you can't use it with the typical `using` block pattern**.

A well-known approach of the shared instance like `HttpClient` cannot be used in `SmtpClient`.

> **Unlike `HttpClient`, the `Send`/`SendAsync` methods are not thread thread-safe**. So unless you want to introduce your own synchronization scheme, you can't use it that way either. In fact, the documentation for `SmtpClient` warns,
>
> > There is no way to determine when an application is finished using the SmtpClient object and it should be cleaned up.
>
> By contrast, the **SMTP client in MailKit represents a simple
> connection to a single server.** By eliminating the complexity caused
> by internal connection pools, it actually makes it easier to create an
> application-specific pool for MailKit's connection object.

Ref: [MailKit Officially Replaces .NET's SmtpClient](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/MailKit-MimeKit-Official#)

Comment: It is NOT obsolete, it's a bug, MS is still trying to fix :-) https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/1876

Answer (score 1):

As of today, [SmtpClient in .NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) is usable but the official doc marks it as obsolete and recommends against using it (for OP's question, the answer is no, it wasn't obsolete in .NET Framework 4.7).

> The SmtpClient class is obsolete in Xamarin. However:
>
> - It is included in the .NET Standard 2.0 and later versions and therefore must be part of any .NET implementation that supports those
>   versions.
> - It is present and can be used in .NET Framework 4 through .NET Framework 4.8.
> - It is usable in .NET Core, but its use isn't recommended.

Comment: And what is the recommended alternative?

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole according to (MS recommendation)[https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md], you should use external library like [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any trace of `System.Obsolete` inside `.NET Framework 4.7.2` for SmtpClient class. Does this mean that this class is no longer obsolete?

Because in [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) it states clearly, `This API is now obsolete.`

**EDIT:**

SmtpClient  is not obsolete, this is due to a bug in the documentation.
See Issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/2986).

Comment: On the contrary, it's actually and functionally obsolete. Just because the attribute is missing doesn't mean that all of the problems suddenly disappeared