# What could be reasons that Microsoft retired SmtpClient?

Tags: .net, networking, smtp, smtpclient

In .NET Framework 4.7 doc, [Microsoft marked `SmtpClient` obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517434/is-system-net-mail-smtpclient-obsolete-in-4-7/43517528?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) with the following reason:

> SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly
> recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and
> https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead

I am curious and no expert in this area. What could be this "poorly designed" that MS had to recommend an outside library instead? How bad it is for projects that still use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: Sorry I disagree. This question is more about "technical design" that I want to know, than wanting to ask for Microsoft's reason. It's good to improve yourself knowing what Microsoft team messed up so you don't do that in the future should you happen to come across the same design.

Comment: The API is NOT obsolete! MS Docs are generated from code, and this api is marked Obsolete in Xamarin/Mono. There's a bug that MS is still trying to fix, see this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517434/is-system-net-mail-smtpclient-obsolete-in-4-7/

Comment: Today I checked again for [.NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient?view=netcore-3.1#remarks), though it's not obsolete, the official doc still recommends against using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SmtpClient` does not supports DKIM (or SPF) authentication. It does not send naturally `RSA` keys and some mail providers consider the key less than 1024bits as spam like `gmail` or `orange`.

Check the "A message I sent from my domain wasn't authenticated" paragraph [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?visit_id=1-636637220870021530-2862990042&p=email_auth&hl=en&rd=1).

I recently changed my implementation too, and i advise `MailKit` : the code definition is pretty much the same (allow you to keep a `MailMessage` object), and it works very well !

```
using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
      client.Connect(Host, Port, UseSsl);
      client.Authenticate(Credential.UserName, Credential.Password);
      client.Send(MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(new MailMessage()));
      client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why MS does not patch its implementation but instead refers to an external package?

Comment: I don't know, not enough time maybe to implement DKIM or planned to a futur version (?)

Comment: I had SmtpClient working fine until I read that MS recommends MailKit. Giving it a try using .Net 5, just failed to connect right out of the gate. This should just work. 
using (var client = new SmtpClient()) 
client.Connect(_SMTP, _PORT, false); I am going back to SmtpClient.

Comment: @GregoryBologna, MailKit works fine, I think you have a reference conflict, have you try with MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient ?

Comment: It fails on SSL, but I have it set to false. I'm on .NET 5, could there be an issue here? Here's my test code.
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("'Test' <no-reply@example.com>", "no-reply@example.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Greg B", "gregb@example.com"));
message.Subject = "test";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain"){Text = @"mail message test"};
using (var client = new SmtpClient()){
client.Connect(_SMTP, _PORT, false);
client.Send(message);
client.Disconnect(true);}

Comment: @GregoryBologna Please ask your question in another topic using screenshot or detailled message error