# C# Sending an email using default credentials: exception

Tags: c#, smtp, exchange-server

I am trying to send an email using default credentials and the SMTPClient.

The exception I get is:

> The SMTP Server requires a secured connection, or the client was not authenticated. The serverresponse was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated.

The code I am trying to use:

```
public void SendEmail(List<string> recipients, string subject, string body)
{
    if (recipients.Count == 0)
        return;

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    foreach (string to in recipients)
    {
        mail.To.Add(to);                
    }

    mail.From = new MailAddress("email@email.com");
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Host = "smtprelay.email.com";

    //client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@email.com", password);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

    client.EnableSsl = true;
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    try
    {
        client.Send(mail);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message);
    }
    mail.Dispose();
}
```

I tested with EnableSsl = true and false, neither worked. If I set UseDefaultCredentials to false, and give them via NetworkCredential, then it works.

Is there some setting in exchange or such that needs to be set?

Edit: int the ServerCertificateCallback, I get:
'((System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient)s).ServicePoint.Address' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

and sslPolicyErrors was System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Does that mean the group policies do not allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange requires either a valid domain account (login/pw) or an IP address that your postmaster has configured as allowable.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code below

```
public static void logMail(string err)
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@email.com", "password");
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.Host = "mail.email.com";

            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@email.com", "test");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("vb_error@email.com"); 
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Subject = "Error";
            mail.Body = "<b>Error Message:</b> " + err;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

Comment: Oh, I know that it works when I provide the NetworkCredentials. But its supposed to run without us altering the app.config XML every single time the policies require a change in password.

Comment: @SinisterMJ If you don't want to use credentials, you need to have the postmaster configure Exchange to allow your machine without authentication.

Comment: @TerryCarmen but then what is the default credentials? I mean, I can use Outlook on my system just fine, and it uses the Windows Login to access the mails, so why can't my code do the same?

Comment: SMTPClient is obsolete. It may not actually work. Contact your postmsaster and ask him what the specific error message was. S/he should be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: If it is obsolete, what is the current C# way to send an email using the exchange account of the logged in user?

Comment: @SinisterMJ See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517434/is-system-net-mail-smtpclient-obsolete-in-4-7/43517528#43517528